# Nonlinear PDE - Coefficients do not evaluate to a numerical scalar

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a nonlinear differential equation but I get an error message regarding the coefficients. Please help ..

```
n = 1/2;
cof = ((1/4 (Inactive[D][u[r, θ], r])^2 + 
   1/4/r^2 (Inactive[D][u[r, θ], θ])^2)/2)^((n - 1)/
2);
NDSolveValue[{1/r D[cof  r  Inactive[D][u[r, θ], r], r] + 
1/r D[cof  1/r  Inactive[D][
    u[r, θ], θ], θ] == -1, 
  DirichletCondition[u[r, θ] == 0, True]}, 
 u[r, θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: What should "u[r, \[Theta]] == 0" mean? You are setting the function you are looking for to zero.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the method of the false transient to solve this problem as follows:

```
n = 1/2; r0 = 10^-6; 
U[0][r_, \[Theta]_] := (r - r0) (1 - r); reg = 
 Rectangle[{r0, 0}, {1, Pi}];
Do[cof = ((1/4 (D[U[t - 1][r, \[Theta]], r])^2 + 
       1/4/r^2 (D[U[t - 1][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2)/2)^((n - 1)/2);
 U[t] = NDSolveValue[{1/r D[cof r D[u[r, \[Theta]], r], r] + 
      1/r D[cof 1/r D[u[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]] == -1, 
    DirichletCondition[u[r, \[Theta]] == 0, True]}, u, 
   Element[{r, \[Theta]}, reg], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
       "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/30^2}}];, {t, 1, 6}]
```

Iterations converge quickly and finally we have numerical solution at `t=6`

```
Table[Plot3D[U[i][r, \[Theta]], Element[{r, \[Theta]}, reg], 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLabel -> i], {i, 6}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

For `n=2` there is no limit for iterations with $\Delta t=1$. In this case we introduce parameter of iterations `t0` and define equation in a parabolic form as follows

```
n = 2; r0 = 10^-6; 
U[0][r_, \[Theta]_] := (r - r0) (1 - r) Sin[\[Theta]]; reg = 
 Rectangle[{r0, 0}, {1, Pi}]; t0 = 1/10;
Do[cof = ((1/4 (D[U[t - t0][r, \[Theta]], r])^2 + 
       1/4/r^2 (D[U[t - t0][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]])^2)/2)^((n - 1)/2);
 U[t] = NDSolveValue[{1/r D[cof r D[u[r, \[Theta]], r], r] + 
      1/r D[cof 1/r D[u[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]] == -1 + (u[
          r, \[Theta]] - U[t - t0][r, \[Theta]])/t0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[r, \[Theta]] == 0, True]}, u, 
   Element[{r, \[Theta]}, reg], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
       "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/20^2}}];, {t, t0, 12 t0, t0}]
```

Visualization of numerical solution on every step

```
Table[Plot3D[U[i][r, \[Theta]], Element[{r, \[Theta]}, reg], 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLabel -> i], {i, t0, 
  12 t0, t0}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Note, there are several examples of application of the  method of the false transient on this forum and on [the page](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064).

Comment: Can you please have a look when n=2. The solution seems to unsettle with time. I appreciate your help ...

Comment: @Rajai  Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Wonderful ... Thank you so much ...